# Should questions conditioned on price include the location of the buyer?

Tags: discussion

Prices may vary depending on the location. Should questions conditioned on price include the location? (e.g. [What's a good non-iPhone smartphone that's reasonably priced and specced?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3/40))

Comment: Dupe. The currency they specify may give you some clue. In the linked question, I specified GB£, with its equivalent current conversion in US$

Comment: thanks, I didn't see the question buried amongst others.